# Match correct regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

```
$package=br.com.example.pc1.test
search=$(adb shell pm list packages | grep "$package")
```

> br.com.example.pc1 - match :(
>
> br.com.example.pc1.test - match :)

I want to give math to finish it: br.com.example.pc1.test

I have try "$package$" to get in final of line but not working

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what the issue is? You're matching results you don't want to match?

Comment: Also note that shell variable _assignments_ must _not_ be `$`-prefixed; you only use the `$` to _reference_ variables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to match a variable value *literally* using `grep`: use the `-F` option, which performs a *literal* substring search (rather than interpreting the search string as a *regular expression*, which `grep` does by default):

```
package='br.com.example.pc1.test'
search=$(adb shell pm list packages | grep -F "$package")
```

Note that this will perform a *substring* search on each line.

---

If your intent is to match `'br.com.example.pc1.test'` *exactly* (i.e., only if an *entire input line* matches), add `-x`:

```
package='br.com.example.pc1.test'
search=$(adb shell pm list packages | grep -Fx "$package")
```

---

If your intent is to match substrings that *start* with `br.com.example.pc1.test` but contain additional components, simply append `.` to the search string:

```
package='br.com.example.pc1.test'
search=$(adb shell pm list packages | grep -F "$package.")
```

---

However, that would still match lines with characters *before* `br.com.example.pc1.test`.

To make sure that the search string only matches at the *start of the line*, you'll need a regular expression with anchor `^`:

```
package='br.com.example.pc1.test'
search=$(adb shell pm list packages | grep "^${package//./\\.}\.")
```

Note how Bash parameter expansion `${package//./\\.}` is used to escape the `.` chars. in the variable value as `\.` to ensure that `grep` treats them as *literal* `.` chars in the context of a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue. I guess you want the regex to work the other way around, try this instead of grep

```
$ search=$(adb shell pm list packages | awk -v k=$package 'k~$0')
```

or simply change your package definition to the substring `br.com.example.pc1`